# Windows Azure Web App File Storage Limit Quota

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I have this web app on Windows Azure on "Free" scale. On management portal, I see web app is using 650MB of 1GB my file storage limit. I've checked all the files over FTP, including Log Files and those extra packages that Azure installs. There is nothing there to make it reach that level.. Max 200MB maybe... Any idea what can be the reason and how can I fix this?

Comment: I don't see how anyone is going to be able to help you, since you haven't posted anything about your actual files, just your guess at what you've consumed. You might consider connecting to your deployment via Kudu (`yoursite.scm.azurewebsites.net`) to explore your entire file system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Noldor, Please refer to the article [File structure on azure](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/File-structure-on-azure) to know the sets of files & dirs on Azure WebApp, and check the directories which include the possible increasing files, such as `LogFiles`, `site/repository`, `site/deployments`(if using [deployment slots](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-staged-publishing/)) and your directory for uploading files.

Comment: I had checked all files but i had ignored just one file in the LogFiles root folder. Because it was a PHP log file named "php_errors.log", and my website wasn't PHP at all.. But apparently it was 462MB somehow. I'll checkout the website and see what's going on about PHP.. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using git or some version control mechanism, there will be some history files hidden in your project folder. Check the folder size of /YOUR_PROJECT/.git/ for git.